# What teshuvot address educating children on inappropriate touch?

Tags: halacha, children-parenting, sexuality, chinuch-education

A friend of a non-observant family shared a story which inspired this question.

Two cousins were playing together. The boy was about 7 years old. The girl was about 3 years old. Early on, the mother (mother-A) of the 3 year old girl had educated her on what is and is not appropriate touch. After the two cousins were playing, the girl informed mother-A that the boy had 'touched' her inappropriately. Mother-A did not take this lightly (being a victim of family molestation) and informed her sister - mother-B - of what had transpired.

Mother-B was certain that her son would not intentionally do this. It is too easy to touch a 'forbidden' area (which could be respectively appropriate generally, yet forbidden to some i.e. touching the thigh) by accident. She also understood that a three year old might get an 'idea' of what inappropriate touch is but still does not have discernment to know what is malicious or not.

Mother-B talked her sister out of making this an issue that could destroy the family. Mother-A dropped it. Unfortunately, there was still recoil. Mother-B warned her son to never be alone with the little girl again. And though the cousins today have a great relationship, mother-A (aunt) and the boy (nephew) do not.

If molestation runs in the family, does educating children start earlier than if not? Does the gender being educated affect how and when education proceeds? Like in our story if a parent is a victim of molestation, is it advised for the parent to first address it within him/herself for a better educational outcome and emotional development of the child?

Comment: The story that motivated this question is very unclear to me. (Was it the three- or the seven-year-old or some other child who touched the three- or the seven-year old? Which kid's mother convinced the other to ignore the issue? How does ignoring the issue equate to "early preventative steps were taken"? What does "the discernment of such a case was insufficient and primed to assume the worst"?) But no matter: that's not your question, it's just a story, so I guess I can ignore it. As to your questions, you seem to have two, one each in your last two paragraphs. But [continued]

Comment: [continued] the second of those is also very unclear to me. "I do understand in this situation molestation was in the family (the mother a victim) so early preventative steps were taken, but could this effect instruction to a child?" Can early preventative steps effect instruction? I guess it depends what the steps are. Certainly instruction can help to effect early prevention. Or did you mean to ask whether a history of molestation can effect instruction? Or did you mean to ask whether a history of molestation can affect instruction?

Comment: One of the leagal ages in Russian is that age when they are aware but do not want it

Comment: But Regarding the obligation to teach it seems it is only when they can do it (what you teach them) so from the age they can understand and do (not do) what you tell them you are obligated

Comment: There are so many aspects of "sexual awareness" that all have different appropriate times. The notion of private parts certainly is taught pretty early. Well before discussing things people probably don't want me listing here.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Not sure how to request a review of my edit to remove hold on question.

Comment: @Re'eh An edit to a closed question sends it to the review queue for reopening.

Comment: I am not sure that it is only a tora question, and a good approach may be given by professional. Very important topic. Shkoyech. ask professionals, and then we can spoke here.

Comment: You could make it a great deal clearer how this post is on-topic by adding in more about why you suspect that there may be responsa that deal with this type of question and what you already know about what responsa or other sources of Jewish tradition say about this general area.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Thank you. Sorry, still learning how to use MY. I assumed there would be a responsa on this issue. I am slightly aware of yichud discussions that could have potentially prevented the above scenario. If your comment should have been translated as 'did you do your homework', the answer is no. Not thoroughly, at least.